# Collection naming convention

Tags: naming-conventions

how should I name array that holds widths of columns? I would use:

```
int[] columnsWidths;
```

but I saw in many places names like:

```
columnWidths
```

or

```
colWidths
```

Of course "widths of columns" is only an example.

Moreover, I think there is also another case, when 2 words are not 2 separate words, but create some kind of name, e.g.

```
class TableView
```

How in this case variable's name should look like?

```
TableView[] tableViews;
```

or

```
TableView[] tablesViews;
```

Answer (score 0):

Read [Code Complete](http://www.cc2e.com/).  But there is no right or wrong answer -- choose what suits you and your colleagues and be consistent.